# Валидация IP адреса в input

Tags: javascript, html

Есть обычный `input`:

```
<input type="text" size="16">
```

Нужно чтобы в него можно было ввести только IP адрес в формате `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.
Если поставить `type=text`, то можно ввести чего угодно.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Ну вообще-то IP не обязан вводиться именно по этому шаблону... наберите в адресной строке 1089053800 и попадите на 64.233.164.104 (www.google.com). 64.233.164.104  = ((64*256+233)*256+164)*256+104 = 1089053800.

Answer (score 7):

Вам надо использовать `pattern` аттрибут HTML5

```
<input type="text" size="16" pattern="YourPattern">
```

Для IP можно использовать паттерн:

```
"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
```

Полный код:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" size="16" pattern="^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: @Regent добавил

Comment: В принципе, если автору нужна валидация, а не маска, то вполне себе вариант, без лишнего JS.

Comment: Паттерн не позволяет ввести адрес с ведущими нулями в октетах, что в общем неправильно.

Comment: @Akina да, вижу, спасибо, поправил

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да не, на самом деле, вы сломали, а не поправили. Теперь можно вводить `333A333B333C333`, что неверно по двум пунктам: можно вводить больше `255`, вместо точки можно указать любой символ.

Comment: @Regent спасибо, поправил, ясно тогда почему в оригинальном столько кода, обработка этого 255 идёт, жаль Regex не поддерживает подобные проверки нормально.

Comment: Ведущих нулей так и не будет в моём примере, так как таковой задачи не стоит в вопросе, и искать более "правильный" паттерн смысла не вижу.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин справедливости ради стоит отметить, что в вопросе вообще речь идёт только о формате `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. А касательно ведущих нулей, рег. выражение будет выглядеть как-то так: `^(([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$`